# PHP: move_upload_file not working

Tags: php, file-upload

I have a folder called team1->uploads->upload_file.php file. upload_file.php uploads a file but has to put it in the uploads directory so I was using ../ to go up a folder. File permissions are 700. I have

```
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
  "../uploads/".$_FILES["file"]["name"]);
```

I get the following error:

```
Warning: move_uploaded_file(../uploads/profile.jpg): failed to open stream: Permission denied in        D:\inetpub\wwwroot\vhosts\cs5339\team1\Produce\upload_file.php on line 31 Warning:     move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move 'C:\Windows\Temp\php938F.tmp' to '../uploads/profile.jpg' in    D:\inetpub\wwwroot\vhosts\cs5339\team1\Produce\upload_file.php on line 31 registered
```

Anyone know how to fix this? Is there another way to upload files?

Comment: Check with your web server configuration, namely related with `move_uploaded_file()` functions, is it is ON or OFF.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

set permissions to 777 on the uploads folder, you can do that directly on the folder or using php:

```
chmod("../uploads/", 777);
```

Comment: ... only need 3 dots or just 2?

Comment: yep 2 dots, i was referring to the path in general.. `'../uploads/'` should work

Comment: Alternatively you can try a little test: `echo file_exists('../uploads/')? 'yes':'no';
echo file_exists($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"])? 'yes':'no';`