# How to eliminate permission denied as a warning while using move_upload_file?

Tags: php, file-upload, permission-denied

When I try to upload a file on my system using and moving it using move_upload_file, it shoots the following error:

> Warning:
>   move_uploaded_file(/Data/destination_folder/file_name.csv): failed
>   to open stream: Permission denied in
>   /var/www/html/mysite/fileHandler.php on line 110
>
> Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpxqyBmf' to
>   '/Data/destination_folder/file_name.csv' in
>   /var/www/html/mysite/fileHandler.php on line 110

The code works fine on my collegue's system and we have assigned the same ownerships and permissions for the required folders. To try and eliminate it i have even tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17257380/move-uploaded-file-gives-failed-to-open-stream-permission-denied?answertab=oldest#tab-top) , [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8103860/move-uploaded-file-gives-failed-to-open-stream-permission-denied-error-after)and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16386378/php-move-upload-file-not-working). The issue still persists.
Following are the permissions for my destination folder:

> drwxrwxrwx.  2 apache apache 4096 May 12 15:47 destination_folder

On checking if the file is uploaded using

```
if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES["efile"]["tmp_name"]))
```

it returns true.

I have absolutely no idea what else could be the issue.
Can anyone spot the mistake i might be doing?

EDIT:
If it helps, the uploaded file doesn't appear in the tmp folder!

Comment: Change destination_folder permission to 777

Comment: Check all the permissions of all the folders in the path, including the parent folders.

Comment: As i have mentioned above the destination folder already has 777 permission and owner as apache

Comment: @deceze:The parent folder(Data) also has the same permissions and ownership

Comment: use `is_writeable` to verify your script can write to that path. http://php.net/is_writeable